# JQuery IE Select Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

Having some trouble w/ IE7. IE8, Chrome, Firefox all work fine, but IE7 won't execute this code.

Here's the HTML Select (Snippet)

```
<form name="frmCat" action="index3.html" method="get">
            <select id="mySelect" onChange="onchange1((this).options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
                <option>Select a Category</option>
            </select>
```

and here is the JavaScript that runs just fine in other browsers (AJAX snippet):

```
function onchange1(catname){
    //alert(catname);
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "xml/categories.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                var div = $('#epcf-wrap');
                var findval = "Cat"
                $(xml).find('Cat').each(function(){
                    var cval = $(this).attr('name');
                                            if(catname === cval){
                                            // I bet there is an easier way to do this
                                            var xmlArr = [];
                                            var xml_EPCF_1_1        = $(this).find('EPCF_1_1').text();
```

I've read that there is some sort of issue w/ IE7 and AJAX and I've seen some hints that there should be some form of MSIE check being done but I'm new to JavaScript and JQuery and nothing I've found aligns very clearly to what I'm doing here.

Thoughts?

Comment: Which part is not working? Error message?

Comment: If you were to show the whole function there wouldn't be a trailing comma at the end of the object you pass to `$.ajax()` would there, i.e., a comma just before the closing `}`? IE doesn't like that (and quite frankly I agree with it) but other browsers don't mind. What does "won't execute" mean? Do you get an error? Does your function get the correct value in its `catname` argument (as from your commented `alert(catname)`)?

Comment: No error messages. Thanks to this post however I now know how to put an error handler in - I'm trying that now.  The full code was entirely too big to post here but is available online at http://mdihosting.com/5/Projects/VRACC/index3.html

Comment: @nnnnnn — a trailing comma in an object literal is a syntax error and should throw an error before any excution begins (it does in IE 8, where the OP says the code runs). Is that what happens? I'm not a fan of nested object literals, particularly when function expressions are included—they're a real pain to debug.

Comment: @RobG - The question did say the code "won't execute", but I had missed that it works in IE8 so yes, you're right that the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just not use the inline javascript. Use the jQuery way.

```
$('#mySelect').change(function(){
    //You can get the select value by the way below.
    var catname = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml/categories.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            var div = $('#epcf-wrap');
            var findval = "Cat"
            $(xml).find('Cat').each(function(){
                var cval = $(this).attr('name');
                if(catname === cval){
                    //....
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If I did that how could I pass the variable 'catname' from the select? How would one handle the (this).options[this.selectedIndex].value grab? wait - I saw it :( I've got tunnel vision on this

Comment: Just tried this - no joy. It also stopped it from working in firefox

Comment: Yes sir... I copied and pasted the code and then deleted the onChange= statement. I posted the entire code online at http://mdihosting.com/5/Projects/VRACC/index3.html

Comment: Updated w/ the code you provided here: http://mdihosting.com/5/Projects/VRACC/index4.html

Comment: @ChadM You missed `)` in line 601

Comment: @ChadM First make sure there is no syntax error in your code.

Comment: I've gone line by line using Komodo and nothing has jumped out thus far. I'm going to google search and see if there is anything online that will highlight syntax errors. The code did come back as W3C compliant, but on the HTML5 beta spec.

Comment: @ChadM You should delete `onChange=""` completely.

Comment: Tried both ways - dang I wish I had better tools, komodo is ok but I'm just learning JavaScript and JQuery, this is my first attempt at doing anything useful and I'm getting hung up here, work is limited to IE7 so despite it working on FF if IE7 fails I just wasted 2 weeks :(

Comment: @ChadM jQuery is cross browser, you can use firebug to debug your code.

Comment: I'm digging into firebug now. I hope you'll check back tomorrow once I have a chance to take a look, you've helped quite a bit

Comment: Finally got it - IE7 demands a value be set for the option, I went back through and added values for all of the options and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem to use ajax in IE7.

please add an error handler to the ajax call, and see what error message is returned.

also make sure your method gets the proper parameter.

last,

```
 $("#myselect").change(handler(event))
```

sounds a bit cleaner. 
this is in the jquery doc at: 
http://api.jquery.com/change